# Валидация и отправка формы с recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Есть страница с простой формой - имя, телефон и почта. Инпуты валидируются js-плагинами, письмо приходит на почту, но-их приходит два, с разницей в 5-10 сек. В консоль ничего не выводится, будто рекапча не работает. Может, я не правильно объединил скрипт отправки со скриптом валидации? (токены скрыты)

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let tk = "";

    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
      grecaptcha
        .execute("token", {
          action: "homepage",
        })
        .then(function (token) {
          tk = token;
          document.getElementById("token").value = token;

          const data = new URLSearchParams();
          for (const pair of new FormData(document.querySelector("form"))) {
            data.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
          }
          fetch("send.php", {
            method: "post",
            body: data,
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
              if (result["om_score"] >= 0.5) {
                console.log("Человек");
                // отправка данных на почту
                let selector = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]');
let im = new Inputmask('+7 (999) 999-99-99');
im.mask(selector);

let validateForms = function(selector, rules, successModal, yaGoal) {
new window.JustValidate(selector, {
    rules: rules,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        let formData = new FormData(form);

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Отправлено');
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.open('POST', 'mail.php', true);
        xhr.send(formData);

        form.reset();

        
    }
});
}

validateForms('.form__callback', { email: {required: true, email: true}, tel: {required: true} }, '.popup-done', 'send goal');
              } else {
                console.log("Бот");
              }
            });
        });
    });
  });
```

```html
<form
            action="mail.php"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
            class="form__callback"
            method="POST"
          >
            <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" />
            <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="project" />
            <input type="hidden" name="admin_email[]" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Тема письма" />
            <h2 class="form__heading">Заказать обратный звонок</h2>
            <label class="form__input">
              <span>Ваше имя</span>
              <input type="text" name="Имя" />
            </label>
            <label class="form__input">
              <span>Номер телефона</span>
              <input
                type="tel"
                data-validate-field="tel"
                name="Телефон"
                placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__"
              />
            </label>
            <label class="form__input">
              <span>Адрес электронной почты</span>
              <input 
              type="email" 
              data-validate-field="email" 
              name="Почта" />
            </label>
            <input
              value="Отправить"
              class="form__button"
              type="submit"
              disabled="disabled"
              id="submit"
            />

            <label class="form__check">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onchange="document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !this.checked;"
              />
              <span
                >Нажатием на кнопку я даю свое согласие на обработку
                персональных данных в соответствии с указанными здесь
                условиями.</span
              >
            </label>
          </form>
```

Comment: Я вижу в коде у Вас вызов двух `.php`-файлов - `send.php` и `mail.php` за что каждый из них отвечает?

Comment: @delikates-send.php- скрипт для рекапчи, mail-для обработки формы и отправки с помощью PHPMailer

Comment: Теперь понятно. Если два раза приходит, значит во-первых у Вас не срабатывает  `e.preventDefault();` и получается, что не дожидаясь ответа от рекапчи форма все же сабмитится. Затем тоже самое происходит после ответа рекапчи. Попробуйте убрать перехват сабмита и просто сделать вызов всего кода по клику на кнопку. Вижу кучу `promisses` - они точно все корректно отрабатывают? Вобщем я бы упростил код, обошелся бы для тестирования обычными $ajax, а дальше по мере отладки приводил к этому же виду.

Comment: @delikates, благодарю, буду пробовать!